# Find out given time is available from different time slot using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

| slot | start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| t1 | 06:00:00 | 09:00:00 |
| t2 | 09:00:00 | 11:00:00 |
| t3 | 11:00:00 | 12:00:00 |

This is sample table.

Given start_time and end_time is **08:30:00 - 09:15:00**

How to write sql query for find slot available or not.

Already try below code is not working

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    TABLE
WHERE ((start_time <= '08:30:00'
        AND end_time >= '09:15:00')
    or((start_time < '08:30:00'
        AND end_time > '08:30:00')
    and(start_time < '09:15:00'
        AND end_time > '09:15:00')))
```

***Excepted Result***

| slot | start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| t1 | 06:00:00 | 09:00:00 |
| t2 | 09:00:00 | 11:00:00 |

**scenario 2**

SAMPLE TABLE

| slot | start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| t1 | 06:00:00 | 09:00:00 |
| t2 | 10:00:00 | 11:00:00 |
| t3 | 11:00:00 | 12:00:00 |

If table like this expected result will get null . Why second table t1 start from 6 - 9 and next slot t2 start from 10 - 11. our given time is 8.30 to 9.15.

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE start_time <= '08:30:00' AND end_time >= '09:15:00'
```

Comment: This is not working because every row start and end time not matching